# AWS Key issue while working with Databricks Mount

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, databricks, aws-databricks

Currently I am facing an issue while dealing with Databricks Mount point created on top of AWS S3 bucket.
I could create the Mount Point in Databricks notebook with below code -

```
ACCESS_KEY = "<<AccessKey>>"
SECRET_KEY = "<<SecreteKey>>"
AWS_BUCKET_NAME = "<<s3 bucket name>>"
MOUNT_NAME = "testmntpnt01"

dbutils.fs.mount("s3a://%s:%s@%s" % (ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, AWS_BUCKET_NAME), "/mnt/%s" % MOUNT_NAME)
```

---

```
Result --> True
```

---

Though,with this mount point is getting created,when tried to list down using dbutils like below -

```
dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/testmntpnt01/')
```

Getting below error :

**com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.common.InvalidMountException: The backend could not get session tokens for path /mnt/testmntpnt01. Did you remove the AWS key for the mount point?**

Being novice in AWS with Databricks can not figure out the actual cause.
Also the provided key & secrete are correct.

Anything I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have exactly the same issue... anyone?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @user3595632 We switched from AWS to Azure and it worked well there. So never explored the AWS issue further.

Comment: @user3595632 are your buckets encrypted and do they use KMS?